# Calling a HTTP request multiple times based on an onchange function

Tags: javascript, jquery, https

I am trying to call a GET request multiple times as an input is filled out. Basically like a filter except it needs to call the API for every new change in the search bar.

The GET works because when the page first loads it loads all the data because the string is empty, but when I type into the search bar it doesn't call the PtSearch() function inside of setsearch().

I log var search in the console and it is being updated as expected so the only issue is the call to the API.

**HTML**

```
        <input id="search"
           type="text"
           class="form-control"
           placeholder="Search"
           aria-label="Example text with button addon"
           aria-describedby="button-addon1"
           onchange="setsearch()"/>
```

**JS**

```
    var search = ""

function setsearch() {
    search = document.getElementById("search").value;
    PtSearch();
};
```

**GET**

```
    function PtSearch() {
    //SEARCH BY FIRST NAME
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var options = {};
        options.url = "https://localhost:44381/api/Patients/" + search;
        options.type = "GET";
        options.dataType = "json";
        options.success = function (patients) {

            patients.forEach(function (patient) {
                $("#result").append(
                    "<tr key=" + patient.patientId + ">" +
                    "<td>" + patient.firstname + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + patient.lastname + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + patient.dob + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + patient.unitId + "</td>" +
                    "<td align=\"center\">" +
                    "<button" +
                    "type=\"button\"" +
                    "class=\"btn btn-sm btn-warning btnspace\">" +
                    "Edit" +
                    "</button>" +
                    "<button" +
                    "type=\"button\"" +
                    "class=\"btn btn-sm btn-danger\"" +
                    "//onClick={this.handleDelete(patient.patientId)}" +
                    ">" +
                    "Delete" +
                    "</button>" +
                    "</td>" +
                    "</tr>"
                )
            });
        };

        options.error = function () {
            $("#msg").html("Error while calling the Web API!");
        };
        $.ajax(options);
    });
```

**API**

```
        // GET: api/Patients/5
    [HttpGet("{search}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Patient>>> GetPatient(string search)
    {

        List<Patient> patient = await _context.Patient.Where(p => p.Firstname.StartsWith(search)).ToListAsync();

        return patient;
    }
```

EDIT

This is what it is doing after using @Qonvex620's code. I removed the initial call so the page loads with nothing, which is on purpose, to test the search bar.

This is the initial load. All is good.
[image: Initial Load]
This is when you type one letter in search bar. Still works normally.
[image: First Letter Searched]
This is when the second letter is typed. You can see that at the bottom of the table it adds the search instead of reloading and only showing the filtered data.
[image]

Comment: I see you applied the updates, but you need to empty your table to solve your new issue. I already mentioned it my answer. $("#result").empty();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please double check your PtSearch function becuase what I observed there's no closing brace on it.

Since you are using already Jquery. Change some of your code to maximize the beauty of it.

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
       var search = $('#search').val();
       PtSearcch(search);   // call search function when script is loaded

     $('#search').change(function() {
         PtSearcch($(this).val());    // call search function when input is  changed
     })

   }

    function PtSearch(search) {
        //SEARCH BY FIRST NAME
            var options = {};
            options.url = "https://localhost:44381/api/Patients/" + search;
            options.type = "GET";
            options.dataType = "json";
            options.success = function (patients) {

                patients.forEach(function (patient) {
                    $("#result").append(
                        "<tr key=" + patient.patientId + ">" +
                        "<td>" + patient.firstname + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + patient.lastname + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + patient.dob + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + patient.unitId + "</td>" +
                        "<td align=\"center\">" +
                        "<button" +
                        "type=\"button\"" +
                        "class=\"btn btn-sm btn-warning btnspace\">" +
                        "Edit" +
                        "</button>" +
                        "<button" +
                        "type=\"button\"" +
                        "class=\"btn btn-sm btn-danger\"" +
                        "//onClick={this.handleDelete(patient.patientId)}" +
                        ">" +
                        "Delete" +
                        "</button>" +
                        "</td>" +
                        "</tr>"
                    )
                });
            };

            options.error = function () {
                $("#msg").html("Error while calling the Web API!");
            };
            $.ajax(options);
  }
```

my advise is to put a delay at least 5 seconds before you call your api to prevent too much request on it.

Comment: So this is sort of working. Except I changed it from ".change" to ".keyup". I also removed the first call to test the search bar. The table filters correctly on the first letter typed, but if I type a second letter, instead of narrowing the result it just adds them to the bottom.

Comment: yes! it's because you are appending the result every request, you can clear first  like this  $("#result").empty() before you append those new results

Comment: So is it just $("#result").empty().append()?

Comment: Yes it's possible, but you can also place it above of it to be more readable.

Comment: Man, thank you so much. It may have been a simple question for you but you just solved a major headache for me.

Comment: Haha, It's part of programming. Thank's, keep coding.

Answer (score 1):

You need an event listener to call setsearch function when there are changes in your input field.
E.g.

```
$( "#search" ).change(function() {
  setsearch();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are already using jQuery so it's better to use On Change Method. This way, you would avoid functions reference order.
I suppose you didn't paste as it is in your project, because here there are some syntax issues too. Like not closing your `function PtSearch()` and not passing the search argument into it! `function PtSearch(search)`.

Here I'm using Archive.org API just for the test but still you can simplify your code into something like this :

```js
  $(document).on('change keyup', '#search', function() {
    var search = $(this).val();
    var options = {};
            options.url = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://archive.org/advancedsearch.php?q="+search+"&fl%5B%5D=identifier&sort%5B%5D=&sort%5B%5D=&sort%5B%5D=&rows=100&page=5&output=json";
            options.type = "GET";
            options.dataType = "json";
            options.success = function (patients) {
$("#result").empty();

                patients.response.docs.forEach(function (patient) {
                    $("#result").append(
                        "<tr key=" + patient.identifier + ">" +
                        "<td>" + patient.identifier + "</td>" +
                        "</tr>"
                    )
                });
            };

            options.error = function () {
                $("#msg").html("Error while calling the Web API!");
            };
            $.ajax(options);
            
                

    });
```

```css
    body {
      background: yellow;
      padding: 20px;
      font-family: Helvetica;
    }
    td{
      border:1px dashed red;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="search"
               type="text"
               class="form-control"
               placeholder="Search"
               aria-label="Example text with button addon"
               aria-describedby="button-addon1">
           <table id="result">
           
           </table>
```